# linq search multiple columns

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to search for a string in multiple columns using ling-to-sql and I'm wondering how to write the `where` clause. This is what I have: I'm passing a list of IDs to search as well as a search term:

```
public List<long> Seach(string TheSearchTerm, List<long> TheIDs)
{

using (SomeDataContext TheDC = new SomeDataContext())
{
    var TheOutput = (from t in TheDC.SomeTable

                     where TheIDs.Contains(t.ID) &&
                      where "TheSearchTerm is in one of the columns"

                     select t.ID).ToList();
    }
}
```

How do I write the second `where` clause the searches for all the columns? I thought of writing a where clause for each column but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var TheOutput = (from t in TheDC.SomeTable

                 where TheIDs.Contains(t.ID) && (
                 t.column1.Contains(TheSearchTerm) ||
                 t.column2.Contains(TheSearchTerm) ||
                 t.column3.Contains(TheSearchTerm) )           
                 select t.ID).ToList();
}
```

You should only have one where clause and combine checks of all columns with `||`.

Comment: Is there anyway to not explicitly include the column names?

Comment: Not with pure linq-to-sql. You could however make a stored procedure that searches all character type columns and then call that SP from the L2S context.

Comment: This isn't an ideal search. Lets say you have author and title columns. Steven King, The Shining wouldn't respond to a searchterm "King Shining" but you probably would want it to.

Answer (score 7):

I have a nuget package called [SearchExtensions](http://ninjanye.github.io/SearchExtensions/index.html) which solves this very issue:

```
var result = TheDC.SomeTable.Search(t => t.Id).EqualTo(TheIDs)
                            .Search(t => t.Column1, t => t.Column2, t => t.Column3)
                            .Containing(TheSearchTerm)
                            .Select(t => t.ID).ToList();
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to search against *all* string properties, you could do the following:

```
var result = TheDC.SomeTable.Search(t => t.Id).EqualTo(TheIDs)
                            .Search().Containing(TheSearchTerm)
                            .Select(t => t.ID).ToList();
```

Both of these methods will create Expressions Trees to send the correct instructions to sql server meaning only the matching records are returned from the database.

Comment: Amazing! It solved my problem. I was looking for searching from multiple columns with ranking.

Comment: Very nice package. Is there a way to search all columns? Like with `table.Search().Containing(Keyword)` but on non string columns too (numbers eventually).