# Linq search (.Contains) across all items in a rows at once?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, generics

Is there a way to do a contains search in linq across all the rows at once rather than list them out.

At the moment I am doing

```
    Data.Where(
        x => x.Name.Contains(searchValue) ||
        x.Address.Contains(searchValue) || 
        x.Id.ToString().Contains(searchValue)... etc
```

What would I like to do is pass in a generic and have it search across all  the data in the rows?

e.g. Data.Where(x => row.Contains(searchValue))

Comment: what do you mean _"across all the rows at once"_?

Comment: oh, do you mean across all **columns/properties**  at once?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linq search multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292618/linq-search-multiple-columns)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ query any of the properties contains string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23527545/linq-query-any-of-the-properties-contains-string)

Comment: Moreover, how `.ToString()` will be translated to SQL at all? May be you should create computed property like `Name + '@' + Id + '@' + ...` and search by it?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [LINQ query any of the properties contains string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23527545/linq-query-any-of-the-properties-contains-string)

You can use reflection but it isn't good for performance

```
list.Where(x => x.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Any(p =>
            {
                var value = p.GetValue(x);
                return value != null && value.ToString().Contains("some string");
            }));
```

**EDIT**:
Like [Fabio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1565525/fabio) said this will filter list in memory, not in sql.

Comment: Will not work for SQL, OP have SQL tag, assume that linq will generate sql

Comment: Side note to the Edit: Filtering in memory i.e. `Data.AsEnumerable().Where(...)` even if it's possible can well appear be *inefficient* (you fecth a *long cursor* into memory and then obtain just a *few records* after filtering)

Answer (score -2):

You can add a property for your data type with a getter method that joins other properties:

```
public string JoinedProperty{
   get{
      return Name+" "+Id.ToString();
   }
}
```

and then this code can help you

```
Data.Where(
    x => x.Contains(searchValue) ... etc
```